# SQL Server database set, configs set - but data from database not displaying with @Html.DisplayFor<>()?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have a question to ask about the SQL Server, Visual Studio and the Entity Framework and how it can update the Model-view with the use of `@HTML.DisplayFor<>()`.

Currently everything is set up as it should be:

1. DbContext is good (Primary key is setup, alongside OnModelCreate(ModelBuilder modelBuilder))
2. SQL Server (local) is good
3. Migrations is good (and is showing up in SQL Server in VS2022)

... So pretty much the IIS Server is able to show my ASP.NET Core web-app without any debug/error information. It just won't show my elements in a `DisplayFor<>()`.

My team and I are kind of perplexed, can someone please help us out? Thank you in advance.

Comment: You should post some small but full code example which reproduces the issue. At least the model class and the view. But note that database, EF etc. has nothing to do with `DisplayFor` as it works with any model class. Except if the data is coming empty, but then `DisplayFor` has nothing to do with the issue, and you need to look at the data retrieval / transfer.

Comment: My apologies. For the late reply, and my lack of internet etiquette but I had solved the problem, I was just being a bit too hasty in coming up with a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it!

I wasn't updating the Controller which was controlling the:

```cs
[HttpGet(IndexExample.cshtml)]
public IActionResult GetIndex()
{
    var model = new IndexModel {
        IndexSubclassGetSetSyntacticSugared = new IndexModel.IndexSubclass()
    };
    return View(model);
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).